# why Test action timer not working when script runs long time?

Tags: jmeter

I am doing some kind of endurance testing with a thread group of 5 threads, and add test action at the end to add delay of 15min after each loop of test execution (please refer to the screenshot), and run overall 32 loops (takes overall around 8 hours).

[image]

[image]

[image]

I let the test run at end of working day using jmeter GUI, and it should take around 8 hours to finish.

Strange thing happens, after jmeter run 4 or 5 loops of 15min, it does not run anymore loops for a couple of hours, then may run 1 or 2 loops in midnight, then continue running in the next morning.

I tried to shorten the delay from 15 min to 1 min or 5 min so that it finishes quicker, then all 32 loops finish with no problem.

So my question comes, how can this happen??? If it's because computer is dormant that jmeter halt, then how come it still runs about an hour after screenlock and also in midnight? If it's because script setting incorrect, then how come if the delay is 1 or 5min it runs ok?

Any suggestions on how to check for this issue? I checked the script settings carefully, nothing suspicious.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Strange thing happens, after jmeter run 4 or 5 loops of 15min, it does
>   not run anymore loops for a couple of hours, then may run 1 or 2 loops
>   in midnight, then continue running in the next morning.

Are you sure that your computer will not sleep / hibernate after about 1 - 1.5 hours of inactivity? I usually got this issue for overnight jobs. The time it runs at midnight may well be the time your antivirus software run (therefore awake your computer).

For these problems, just use a [computer software](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-keep-your-computer-awake-without-touching-the-mouse/) out there and you should be fine. Do notice that some company also set up technical measures to prevent employees have their computer on overnight, better check them out.

Comment: Talked to IT department. This should be it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is due to Test Action sampler.

By the way, according to the [documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action), you're pausing only **current thread** for 15 minutes while others are running as in "Pause" mode "Current Thread/All Threads" combobox value is ignored. If your target is to wait for 15 minutes before next iteration without delivering any load - consider using [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) or i.e. switch to [Ultimate Thread Group](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/#Ultimate-Thread-Group-supfont-color-gray-size-1-since-0-2-1-font-sup)

My expectation is that this is due to non-optimal JMeter configuration. Try the following steps

1. Increase [JVM Heap size](http://crunchify.com/jvm-tuning-heapsize-stacksize-garbage-collection-fundamental/) allocated to JMeter
2. Run your test in [command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
3. Disable all the listeners, especially [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)
4. Consider upgrade to JMeter 3.0

See [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article for more information on above steps and few other JMeter tuning tips.

Comment: what is "current thread" in document? my thread group has 5 threads, which one is the "current" that pauses? Also i've used Synchronizing time before, it can synchronize samples among threads, i do not see how it can be used to wait xxx min before next iteration. Could you elaborate a little more on this?